# Restore commit and branch not push yet but both of them has delete in local and clone agin

Tags: git

I have this issue like this:

after commit whole code i wrote but still not push yet.

And than i delete project and clone that again.

but i checkout that branch is not exit.

Please help me to take look about this.

Thank!

Comment: Then you need some tool to recover data on your HDD, no way to get those data with `git`, as you have never pushed your data to remote.

Comment: Oh. Thanks Kata.